# Rename "unins000.exe" in Inno Setup by editing Install.pas Delphi Unit

Tags: delphi, inno-setup, delphi-2009, uninstallation

I want to make my Inno Setup Script create `uninstaller.exe` files for Uninstallation, not the `unins000.exe` by modifying the Source Code of `Inno Setup Compiler 5.5.9 Unicode`.

I opened the Delphi Unit `Install.pas` which have these codes:

```
procedure GenerateUninstallInfoFilename;
  var
    ExistingFiles: array[0..999] of Boolean;
    BaseDir: String;

    procedure FindFiles;
    var
      H: THandle;
      FindData: TWin32FindData;
      S: String;
    begin
      H := FindFirstFile(PChar(AddBackslash(BaseDir) + 'unins???.*'),
    FindData);
      if H <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then begin
        repeat
          S := FindData.cFilename;
          if (Length(S) >= 9) and (CompareText(Copy(S, 1, 5), 'unins') = 0) and
         CharInSet(S[6], ['0'..'9']) and CharInSet(S[7], ['0'..'9']) and CharInSet(S[8], ['0'..'9']) and
         (S[9] = '.') then
            ExistingFiles[StrToInt(Copy(S, 6, 3))] := True;
        until not FindNextFile(H, FindData);
       Windows.FindClose(H);
  end;
end;

procedure GenerateFilenames(const I: Integer);
var
  BaseFilename: String;
begin
  BaseFilename := AddBackslash(BaseDir) + Format('unins%.3d', [I]);
  UninstallExeFilename := BaseFilename + '.exe';
  UninstallDataFilename := BaseFilename + '.dat';
  UninstallMsgFilename := BaseFilename + '.msg';
end;
```

I want to change this code to create `uninstaller.exe , uninstaller.dat , uninstaller.msg` files when the Setup saves Uninstall Information.

So, if setup detects the old `uninstaller.exe` when trying to reinstall my program without uninstalling its any old Installation, Setup should detect that old `uninstaller.exe` and overwrite it without any user Confirmation.

Compiler Used: `CodeGear RAD Studio with Delphi 2009 Update 4`.

I like to know how can I do this.I will do this for testing purpose only.

After Renaming the `unins000.exe` to `uninstaller.exe` , looks like Inno Setup can't find uninstall log files or any other error.........

[image: Setup Crashes on second re-installation over an old installation]

Thank You For Your Help.

Comment: Probably there's more code that is relevant. Have you considered hiring a programmer or maybe learning to program yourself. A programmer would be able to understand the code and would know how to change it. Obviously you are wanting to make significant changes here by removing the numbering logic.

Comment: But @DavidHeffernan Please...........I will try to understand what you tell me about changing of this code.....I also tried renaming `unins` to `uninstaller`, but I still got three digit at end like `uninstaller000.exe`. How can I remove this `000 / 001 / 002 ............999`?

Comment: Start by reading the code. Do you understand what it does? How do you want to change the numbering logic? Remember that you have omitted much relevant code. I suggest that you are not trying hard enough.

Comment: No..........You're right I'm not a programmer yet...........But I also like to learn how to do such a small change in a code when needed........That's why I try.I think this code does those: Generates Uninstall Executable Names, as @Sertac Akyuz said in a post I read about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you have at least very basic programming skills:

Put a breakpoint on line **UninstallExeFilename := BaseFilename + '.exe';**

Check the **BaseFilename** variable using Watch in IDE.
What does it say?

It should be 'uninstaller' to match your requirement. If it is different them simply watch **BaseFilename** variable and check the value assigned to it.

The line that changes this variable to numbers can be commented out or modified.

Comment: I already tried it. I changed code like `uninstaller` as you told previously but Setup warns me when I reinstalls my program over an old installation telling `The Uninstaller File Exits, Please correct the problem and try again.` I want this code (`FindFiles procedure`) to overwrite any existing `uninstaller.exe` in `{app}` directory...........

Comment: Line H := FindFirstFile(PChar(AddBackslash(BaseDir) + 'unins???.*') searches for existing uninstaller (that with number). Change also this line like 'uninstaller.*' to ignore that uninst000 files.

Comment: but I still getting this error: `Create Process Failed, The File Exists, Code :80` :(............Why that?

Comment: I will become a one later in Future...........If I was a good programmer and had an account in that such a site, I will help anyone without considering if asker is a newbie or an experienced programmer or even not a programmer.............Why you can't do so??? :(

Comment: @Slappy I did what you said, but I still got the same error...........Why this? Is `unins000.exe` is a magical name or else........? I got `CreateFile Failed, The File Exists.........`

Comment: Why don't you read the code and understand what it does. Have you considered doing some debuggjng?

Comment: @David I understood what went wrong and corrected the mistake............The mistake is that when I rename `unins000` as `uninstaller` , there is no anyway to create different `UninstallExe` file name. So `Windows.CreateFile` fails with code `FILE EXISTS`. After I changed Create Uninstall DATA File value from `CREATE_NEW` to `CREATE_ALWAYS` setup overwrites my uninstaller executable fine when over-installing my first installation. Is this the problem as you think?